# how to upload an image from my android app to a specific folder on google drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm using this [code](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android)

to upload an image from my android app to the user's google drive account.

But how can I modify the code to upload the image to folder named "myFolder"?

meaning to that folder is exist and if not - create such folder and then upload the image there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do in order to upload a file to a specific folder is to add the folder's id to the file parents ([ref Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) for `file.insert`).

So the full things you need to do are:

1. Find the folder in drive
2. Create the insert request
3. Add the parent id to the file insert
4. Execute the insert request

**Code**

Find the Folder

Here you can opt for 2 ways: loop all the folders or search for it.

Faster and less resource heavy is to search the folder by name; to do so it's simple:

```
//Search by name and type folder
String qStr = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title = 'myFolder'";

//Get the list of Folders
FileList fList=service.files().list().setQ(qStr).execute();

//Check that the result is one folder
File folder;

if (fList.getItems().lenght==0){
    folder=fList.getItems()[0];

}
```

More info about the possible [search parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters).

Create the insert request is as in the sample

```
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
```

before executing it we need to set the parent
    file.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(folder.getFolderId())));

In the end execute the request
    file.execute();

I haven't tested the code so there might be some typo here and there.

Comment: super. I'll try. Where did you took this from? How can I create a folder if not exist?

Comment: I've deduced the code from the documentation (ref in the answer, and another useful link is the one to the Drive Mimetypes https://developers.google.com/drive/mime-types ). To create a folder you have to create a new file with mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and use the title for the Folder name