# How to upload files to particular folder in Google Drive Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

i am not having issue in uploading files to root folder of google drive i am not able able to find the way to upload the files in specific folder in google drive

i followed this example by google developer 
[here is the link](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#get_the_root_folder)

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#creating_files_programmatically ?

Comment: yes anatoli , but i don't want to upload files to root folder

Comment: Well, you'll need to have a handle for your folder.
Are you using CreateFileActivityBuilder? or creating the file programmatically?

Comment: got any solution yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you specified pertains to [Working with Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#get_the_root_folder) and focuses pretty much on discussing the **root folder** (creating folders, creating files inside folders etc.). I've looked around the community and found this post that is pretty much the same as yours.

First is a post on how to post photos on a specific folder, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20917799/6124253) is pretty much the whole guide on how to do it. Basically, it mentions "***What you need to do in order to upload a file to a specific folder is to add the folder's id to the file parents***"

I think all you have to do now is to tweak around the code according to your preference (with the data type and all).

Comment: Note that the question was about the Android Drive API. The answer you've linked to discusses the REST API.

Comment: It does. I did also mention that the post I got it from is pretty much the same because of the [tag:android] and [tag:google-drive-sdk] tags. S/he can try to integrate the Drive REST API in his/her code, I'm not sure but I think it is possible. S/he can also try the [Creating Files Programmatically](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#creating_files_programmatically) link you provided and do [these steps](http://stackaoverflow.com/a/32062080/6124253), I think it's better. Just providing him/her ideas, ti's all. :)